# Multiple OPTION value to use as GET in form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have searched many solutions and almost all over the internet but found no answer.

I am having a form like:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
 <select id="store" type="text" name="s"> 
        <option valA="value1" valB="value2">Selection 1</option>
        <option valA="value3" valB="value4">Selection 2</option>
 </select>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This form is extended via PHP with MySQL which takes valA and valB from database for each "Selection" in while loop and generate form with that form (given above).

I know that sending it via POST will reload my website with value given by value name. But I need to do it with two values.

So my link when I select one of the options will be:

```
 http://mywebsite.com/index.php?valA=value1&valB=value2
```

Form is still active every time website reloads, so when I choose another option, I want to change it with submit and change URL.

Everything I found is to use multiple option and send two of them at the same time, but I have *no* multiple selection, but one selection with many parameters each (for me - two).

Is it possible to do it via HTML/Form, or I need to use PHP, but how?

I need to reload website - not change it only, because based on valA and valB website will load datatables script based on it and will produce table from database one of the values is just a key to table, another to database.

Comment: A different approach: keep the combination of values on the server and give that combination a specific ID. Put that unique ID in the options to select on the client. Process the ID on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can join your required values with some delimiter, for example:

```
<select id="store" type="text" name="s"> 
    <option value="value1:value2">Selection 1</option>
    <option value="value3:value4">Selection 2</option>
</select>
```

Your url becomes:

```
http://mywebsite.com/index.php?s=value1:value2
```

On server side you can:

```
$parts = explode(':', $_GET['s']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need javascript to achieve that without php

If your php is whats receiving the call then why don't you have a value seperated by a delmiter value="value1|value2"

then in your php I would do the following

```
$values = explode("|",$_GET['s']);
```

then you have $values[0]  and $values[1] - containing the two values